# How do I use a get request AJAX call to my php function?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, get

sorry if this seems like a ridiculous question, however, I've been pulling my hair out for 3 days trying to work out how to do this...

I essentially want to pull out this (query var?) and use the parameters in my current function...

```
?vote=up&comment_id=8
```

Here is my current function:

```
<?php
// This file is used for buildimng the custom comment upvote and downvote functionality.


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_enqueue' );
function ajax_enqueue() {
// Enqueue File from 'inc' folder.
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/ajax/comment_vote_ajax.js', array('jquery') );

// in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as         
ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
    array(  
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 
        'user_id' => get_current_user_id()
    )
);
}

// Same handler function...
function ajax_action() {
global $wpdb;

if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    return;
}

if ( ! isset( $_GET[ 'vote' ] ) && ! isset( $_GET[ 'comment_id' ] ) ) {
    return;
}

$up_or_down = esc_attr( $_GET[ 'vote' ]) ;
if ( ! in_array( $up_or_down, [ 'up', 'down' ] ) ) {
    return;
}

$comment_id = (int) esc_attr( $_GET[ 'comment_id' ] );
if ( $comment_id < 1 ) {
    return;
}

// Retreive the existing comment up/down vote ID's - we don't know who did what at this point..
$vote_user_ids = get_comment_meta( $comment_id, '_vote_user_ids', true );

// If the comment upvote count isn't set, create an empty array.
// This will always be the case on the first instance of a user "upvoting" a comment
if ( ! is_array( $vote_user_ids ) ) {
    $vote_user_ids = [];
}

// Check if the user has already "voted"
if ( array_key_exists( get_current_user_id(), $vote_user_ids ) ) {

    // If the user HAS voted and they are repeating themselves (e.g. the voted up and are trying to do this again) ignore them..
    if ( $up_or_down === $vote_user_ids[ $user_id ] ) {
        return;
    } else {
        // The user voted already but have changed their vote - update this
        //$vote_user_ids[ get_current_user_id() ] = $up_or_down;
        unset ( $vote_user_ids[ get_current_user_id() ] );
    }

} else {

    // The user HAS NOT voted, add them
    $vote_user_ids[ get_current_user_id() ] = $up_or_down;
}

// Whatever the results of ^^ we need to update now
$update_result = update_comment_meta( $comment_id, '_vote_user_ids', $vote_user_ids );
delete_transient( "comment_vote_count_comment_{$comment_id}" );


if ( ! $update_result ) {
    error_log( "Error updating comment meta to update $comment_id to set user ID $user_id $up_or_down." );
}

wp_die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'ajax_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'ajax_action' );
```

// End of the ajax call.
Here is the current script I have...

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
if (!url) url = $(this).attr('href');
name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
if (!results) return null;
if (!results[2]) return '';
return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

$(document).ready(function(){

$("a.upvote").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var comment_id = getParameterByName('comment_id', $(this).attr('href'));

    filters_get = {
        'vote': 'up',
        'comment_id': comment_id
    };

    $.ajax({
      url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
      type: "post", //send it through get method
      data: filters_get,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log( 'comment_id' + ' = ' + comment_id );
        console.dir(data);
        console.log(data);
        $('.comment p').after(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
      }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: `$_GET[ 'comment_id' ]` is how you access comment ID, for instance. In fact it's already used in your code at least once. Same for `$_GET[ 'vote' ]`. The issue I think is that your ajax request sends a POST and not a GET. `type: "get"` will fix it. The comment right next to it "//send it through get method" directly (and rather obviously) contradicts the actual code.

Comment: Should be post and not get

Comment: use `filter_input(INPUT_GET, $name, $filter, $options)` on get and `filter_input(INPUT_POST, $name, $filter, $options)` for post. See http://php.net/manual/de/function.filter-input.php alternative you could use `filter_input_array` if you're working with multiple values

Comment: So after having fiddled with code a little bit more, I realised that the names of my ajax functions weren't the same. I needed to swap out the $_GET request for a $_REQUEST. Change my Jquery Ajax to be a type of 'post' and swap out the 'data' in the success function to 'response'

Comment: $_POST would be better (more specific) than $_REQUEST. $_REQUEST can be used if you don't care whether the request is done via GET or POST, but in your case you're definitely using a POST. It just tightens things up a little bit. As for "Change my Jquery Ajax to be a type of 'post'", well according to your code above it already is? And "swap out the 'data' in the success function to 'response' " - you can call the variable `kdjfgkjfhgkj` if you like, but then all the code has to match it. Currently, above, everything is already using `data` correctly, so why change it?